# How to make characters in Eclipse txt file visible?

Tags: java, eclipse, text

I have a txt file "HighScoreList.txt" in my project. 
The Problem is that there must be characters on that file, but when I open it in Eclipse, its empty. Removing it from eclipse and opening it with notepad removes all characters from that file.
My method writes on that file.

```
public void registerHighScore(Player p) {
    int score = p.getScore();
    String name = p.getName();
    {
        currentHighScores.add("X. "+name+" - "+score); //place doesnt matter as the actual place gets determined in formatHList
        formatHList();
    }
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(HighScoreManager.class.getResource("/highscore/HighScoreList.txt").getPath()));//persistancy
        for (String s : currentHighScores) {
            writer.write(s);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I have checked that there must be characters in the textfile because

```
public ArrayList<String> getCurrentHighScores() {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(HighScoreManager.class.getResource("/highscore/HighScoreList.txt").getPath()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

The ArrayList createt with that method actually contains Strings in the X. Name - Score format.

Comment: Do you have separate source and class folders? Then, Eclipse will copy the file from the source folder to the classes folder whenever the project is rebuild or the file changed, however, your program reads and writes the resource in the classes folder, but Eclipse shows you the original in the source folder not reflecting these changes. And your code will break as soon as you deploy it as jar file or module image, by the way.

Comment: Yes i have seperate folders. Is there a way to work around this other than putting the txt File into the class folder?

Comment: You should not use embedded resources for mutable files at all. Define a dedicated location for them, i.e. neither in the source nor class filer. Or consider other storage solutions, e.g. [the preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/prefs/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks it works now. I store the txt file outside the jar file but in the same directory